# pyramid on webfaction: problems serving static files

Tags: pyramid, webfaction

so i have a site on webfaction that runs pyramid. it's all working ok except some static files are not serving. 4 to be specific and i dont know why.

http://karantan.webfactional.com/static/images/bg2.jpg

this link gives me 404 but the image is there! also same goes for fonts. 3 font links:

http://karantan.webfactional.com/static/css/fonts/titilliumtext25l005-webfont.woff
http://karantan.webfactional.com/static/css/fonts/titilliumtext25l005-webfont.ttf
http://karantan.webfactional.com/static/css/fonts/titilliumtext25l005-webfont.svg

again. all files are there!

as far as i know all other files are serving ok. so does any1 have any idea why this would happened? and how to fix the problem

Comment: So, just to be explicit; there are other files in /static/images and /static/css/fonts that *do* work?

Comment: More importantly: did you use a filesystem path or a package path to register the static assets?

Comment: In case it still doesn't work.. clear your cache if your browser cached something.

Comment: i created nginx static server. problem solved :)

Comment: I can't make this to work.The file is in the filesystem but I can't serve them (it returns 404) http://ltmo.com.ar/static/fonts/entypo.ttf. I've added a .htaccess file but it doesn't make any difference. 
You are using a plain static app?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your comment, WebFaction pointed me to using a nginx static server for this problem, too.  I was running into the same thing with an included TinyMCE library; javascript would serve up fine but some static HTML pages would throw a 404 error.  I'm still not sure why it works that way....